# Pinterest not seeing images

Tags: wordpress, pinterest, nextgen-gallery

I'm using a Wordpress Theme by Elegantia in combination with NextGen Pro. I'm having an issue - Pinterest does not see any images in the NextGen Gallery.

Pinterest picks up any other images on my side just fine. And it also seems to work fine on NextGen installed on other Wordpress sites. So it seems like there is a conflict between my theme and NextGen.

I contacted NextGen, since I pay them for support, and unfortunately they are being fairly useless.

I tested the issue using sharing plugins, Pinterest's button and also Pinterest Safari extension - same result on all of them.

I also tried turning off all other plugins - made no difference.

I'm trying to figure how to trace down what is causing this issue with NextGen and Pinterest on my site and fix it.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you.

Here is my link: http://abclandscaping.com/outdoor-living/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with NextGen Gallery but it looks like it is using Flash to present the images and Pinterest does not play well with Flash. You should look for a Wordpress slideshow plugin that is CSS and Javascript. You might look into BxSlider or Flexslider for Wordpress. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Ohh...why do you think they are using Flash? I didn't notice evidence of that.